# Issue with MediaElement and thread.sleep

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a selection change from a combobox.  When that event occurs, I want to play one media file, pause 5 seconds and then play another media file. What is actually happening is that there is a 5 second pause.  Then only the second media file plays (vb.mp4).  What am I doing wrong here?

```
private void cmb_adGroupZoneOne_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       this.mediaElement.Source = new Uri("C:/fb.mp4");
       this.mediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
       this.mediaElement.Play();

       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

       this.mediaElement.Source = new Uri("C:/vb.mp4");
       this.mediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
       this.mediaElement.Play();
    }
```

Comment: `Play()` is likely not blocking, meaning that when your program calls `Play` it continues immediately on and sleeps, then plays the second mp4.  You are missing the playback of the 1st mp4.   Not sure you can do what you are trying to do on a single thread.   Try starting the 1st mp4, then listening in the `MediaEnded` event and starting the second mp4 from there.    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaended(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<MediaElement Name="mediaElement" MediaEnded="mediaElement_MediaEnded"  />

private void cmb_adGroupZoneOne_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       this.mediaElement.Source = new Uri("C:/fb.mp4");
       this.mediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
       this.mediaElement.Play();

    }


private void mediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

       this.mediaElement.Source = new Uri("C:/vb.mp4");
       this.mediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
       this.mediaElement.Play();  
}
```